# Clickable link in javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add an anchor tag in an alert box using jquery? I am trying to show a clickable link in the alert box of jquery, but I can only get text in the box.

```
alert('<a href= "http://www.google.com">Please read the rules</a>')
```

How do I get this done in jquery?

Comment: [Please read the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: no you cant, if you want to do that have to use modal window alternatives. search google `javascript simple modal popup`

Comment: Please do not use the title field to put the first phrase of your question body. It makes the question very unclear.

Comment: Ok Samurai8 I won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to place any HTML code into alert dialogs. You'd better consider using some JavaScript based dialogs (for example from https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)